# Print all values of a dictionary on the same line -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_dict = {
    '1': 'Apple',
    '2': 'Banana',
    '3': 'Orange'}
```

If I have this dictionary, how can I print only the values on the same line, so it can say "My favorite fruits are: Apple, Banana, Orange"?

Comment: `print("My favorite fruits are: ", end="") ; print(*my_dict.values(), sep=", ")`

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.join`:

```
print(f"My favorite fruits are: {', '.join(my_dict.values())}")
My favorite fruits are: Apple, Banana, Orange
```

Comment: Or just add fruits as different param, `print("My favorite fruits are:", ", ".join(my_dict.values()))`

Comment: I prefer use `f-strings`. In you example, it works because the default separator is space (*sep: string inserted between values, default a space.*)

Comment: Imho, using formatting just for string concatenation is an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Use `my_dict.values()`:

```
>>> f"My favorite fruits are: {', '.join(my_dict.values())}"
'My favorite fruits are: Apple, Banana, Orange'
```